# Detecting triangles using hough transforms

Tags: python, geometry, computer-vision, hough-transform

How would you go about detecting a triangle (of known shape) in an image. The environment is uncluttered and mostly free of other objects. Here is an example [image]

I have looked into hough transforms, used HoughLines to detect lines and then some simple python logic for trying to make triangles out of them. This resulted in a loot of noise, and its almost impossible to find the correct triangle.

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using contrast? If the image above is a representative example, the contrast from the white to the black and then to the green gives a very distinctive feature to be recognised. Make sure to threshold the image before applying edge detection.

You could also try mapping the lines found from contrast to a triangle of the specific size you wanted (I notice you mentioned mapping to triangles, but no mention of using size). Note however that a size constraint would be affected by the distance of the camera from the object.

Also, if you have full control over the object for detection (as it looks like you are using this to detect something of your own making), you could add other shapes within the triangle, or more contrast layers. Full circles are a good shape to use (as most noise won't have a complete loop)

Comment: I've tried to use color information (by attempting to minimize the distance between the target color and the average color of the triangle detection.
Those are all great ideas. I think i will try having many similar triangles nested within one another to try to combat the noise.
PS. Why threshold the image before edge detection?

Comment: Thresholding the image is what uses the contrast to your advantage. Attempting to use contrast in your own functions is much more difficult to get right than simply binary thresholding to a certain point that is good for your application. Check out a thresholding slider example to see what I mean; it will make the triangle stand out almost by itself at a certain amount of thresholding, rendering most of the noise nonexistent. Then you can use edge detection on what is left. This should also mean you don't need many changes to the triangle